# Generating archive list for a blog in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to generate an archive list for blog articles. The archive list should display year and date in reverse chronological order as follows:

```
2013 (21)
    - May (2)
    - April (3)
    - March (5)
    - February (1)
    - January (10)
2012 (10)
    - December (6)
    - November (4)
```

The number inside `()` are the number of posts in that time period. When the year or month of the year has been selected, only the blog posts from that selected time period should be displayed.

So far I've only been able to find out the year and month of each blog post by doing:

```
$posts = Post::all();
$archive = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($post->created_at));
    $month = date('m', strtotime($post->created_at));
}
```

How do I go about achieving the above objectives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For generating a links in some sort of navigation panel you can do most of the processing on DB side and not fetching all the blog posts records with a query like this

```sql
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       MONTH(created_at) month,
       MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name,
       COUNT(*) post_count
  FROM post
 GROUP BY year, MONTH(created_at)
 ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

Output:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | POST_COUNT |
------------------------------------------
| 2013 |     5 |        May |          5 |
| 2013 |     4 |      April |          3 |
| 2013 |     3 |      March |          4 |
| 2013 |     2 |   February |          3 |
| 2013 |     1 |    January |          2 |
| 2012 |    12 |   December |          2 |
| 2012 |    11 |   November |          3 |
```

I'm not an expert in laravel, but it should be achieved with something similar to this

```
$links = DB::table('post')
    ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
    ->groupBy('year')
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

If you want you can add subtotals to year rows like this

```sql
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       MONTH(created_at) month,
       MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name,
       COUNT(*) post_count
  FROM post
 GROUP BY year, MONTH(created_at)
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       13 month,
       NULL month_name,
       COUNT(*) post_count
  FROM post
 GROUP BY year
 ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

Output:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | POST_COUNT |
------------------------------------------
| 2013 |    13 |     (null) |         17 |
| 2013 |     5 |        May |          5 |
| 2013 |     4 |      April |          3 |
| 2013 |     3 |      March |          4 |
| 2013 |     2 |   February |          3 |
| 2013 |     1 |    January |          2 |
| 2012 |    13 |     (null) |          5 |
| 2012 |    12 |   December |          2 |
| 2012 |    11 |   November |          3 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a20eb/9)**

Comment: Thanks. The SQL query worked, but I don't think that is the way of raw queries in Laravel, so it didn't work.

Answer (score 16):

This is the most elegant way to do this would be to pass a closure into the groupBy() collection method.

```
$posts_by_date = Post::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m');
});
```

Then you can loop through it in your blade template similar to this:

```
@foreach ($posts_by_date as $date => $posts)
    <h2>{{ $date }}</h2>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
        {{ $post->content }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Very elegant ! One problem by default, the sort is asc ! Start to 2013, 2014 etc...
How to to sort it in desc ?

Comment: I find the solution : 
News::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->groupBy(function($date)

Comment: This doesn't return exactly what the OP asked, he wanted a list of months with number of posts in each, while this returns the posts themselves, organized in months. It's true you can use `count()` to solve this here, but it still returns a lot of unneeded information... But maybe it's still faster then a custom SQL query? Don't know...

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this for a while as well. By using some more laravel functionality I came to the following solution:

To create the archive:

```
$archive = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->whereNotNull('created_at')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function(Post $post) {
            return $post->created_at->format('Y');
        })
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return $item
                ->sortByDesc('created_at')
                ->groupBy( function ( $item ) {
                    return $item->created_at->format('F');
                });
        });
```

Then to Display (including bootstrap 4 classes):

```
<div class="archive mt-5">
<h4>Archive</h4>

@foreach($archive as $year => $months)
    <div>
        <div id="heading_{{ $loop->index }}">
            <h6 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link py-0 my-0" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#collapse_{{ $loop->index }}"
                        aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapse_{{ $loop->index }}">
                    >
                </button>
                {{ $year }}
            </h6>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_{{ $loop->index }}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_{{ $loop->index }}"
             data-parent="#accordion">
            <div>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    @foreach($months as $month => $posts)
                        <li class="">
                                {{ $month }} ( {{ count($posts) }} )
                        </li>

                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close, but you need to test the data, is that what you're asking?

You could also query for the data.

I'm not saying this is the only way to solve the problem, but how would this work? The for each statement could to store the data into an array, something like this:

```
function checkdate($datein,$posts){

    foreach ($posts as $post){
        $year = date('Y', strtotime($post->created_at)))
        $month = date('m', strtotime($post->created_at)))

        if(($year == $datein->year)||($month == $datein->month)){
        //good
        }
        else {
        //bad
        }
    }
}
```

That would do the trick, but... what if we had filtered data in the first place.  I'll bet Laravel has a better way to handle it.

Yep!  http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

keep reading about polymorphism and querying relations, dynamic properties...