# Laravel generate archive post by year and month

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I would now recover my articles with an archive system ( list ) year and month with Laravel 4.2 .

I manage to retrieve my items per year and per month with no problem (see below)

Here is my controller using the Query builder Laravel

```
public function index(){
 $post_links = DB::table('posts')
          ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
          ->groupBy('year')
          ->groupBy('month')
          ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
          ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
          ->get();

          return View::make('home.index')->with(array(
          'post_links'=>$post_links,

      ));
}
```

And my view

```
 <ul id="show-year">
                @foreach($post_links as $link)
                {{--{{dd($link)}}--}}
                 {{--Show year--}}
                     <li>
                          <a title="" href="#">
                              <span>
                                <strong>{{$link->year}}</strong></a>&nbsp;<span class="post-count">{{$link->post_count}}</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                              </span>
                              </li>
                          </a>
                          {{--show month--}}
                          <ul id="show-month">
                            <li class="month-content">
                               <a href="">
                                  <span>
                                    <strong>{{$link->month_name}}</strong>
                                  </span>
                            </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                       </li>
                @endforeach
        </ul>
```

I recovered my data years and months but it adds a year each month to her together in this way

2015 ( 21)
- May ( 2)
- April (3)
- March ( 5)
- February (1)
- January (10)
2016 (10)
- December (6)
- November (4)

I don't understand why it does not group me in the same year and generates me every time a new entry of year for each month.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this way  ->groupBy(['year', 'month'])

Comment: when i debug $posts_links i have aan array of object like that array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[362]
      public 'year' => string '2016' (length=4)
      public 'month' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'month_name' => string 'January' (length=7)
      public 'post_count' => string '1' (length=1)
 My year i not group

Comment: how can i foreach for having an array of year with month

Answer (score 0):

For generating a links in some sort of navigation panel you can do most of the processing on DB side and not fetching all the blog posts records with a query like this

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       MONTH(created_at) month,
       MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name,
       COUNT(*) post_count
  FROM post
 GROUP BY year, MONTH(created_at)
 ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

Output:

```
| YEAR | MONTH | MONTH_NAME | POST_COUNT |
------------------------------------------
| 2013 |     5 |        May |          5 |
| 2013 |     4 |      April |          3 |
| 2013 |     3 |      March |          4 |
| 2013 |     2 |   February |          3 |
| 2013 |     1 |    January |          2 |
| 2012 |    12 |   December |          2 |
| 2012 |    11 |   November |          3 |
```

something like this code

```
  $links = DB::table('post')
        ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month, MONTHNAME(created_at) month_name, COUNT(*) post_count'))
        ->groupBy('year')
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->orderBy('yea`enter code here`r', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('month', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

original solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494821/generating-archive-list-for-a-blog-in-laravel)